# How do I open a Windows Store Applicaton in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-store

So I am used to programming windows forms applications. In desktop application I can open them by doing:

```
    Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notebook.exe"
    p.Start()
```

If I want to open something like the weather app for Windows Store then this method does not work.  Can someone direct me to resources on how I would accomplish this?

Comment: That's not possible.  Only the user can start a Store app.

Comment: Can you at least tell what application can have focus?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the point, you want to open metro application from other metro application? or from desktop application a metro application or a desktop application from metro application?

Comment: I want to use a windows desktop application to open various metro apps

Comment: Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateInstance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902.aspx

if your goal is to support automatic testing then check this blog entry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if this answers your question @ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/79092f3f-917d-41e5-a67f-c25e851bbb14/how-to-start-and-end-metro-applications-from-c-code